# CSV Import with where clause in Model Codeigniter

Tags: csv, codeigniter, model-view-controller, model, controller

This is my code. I don't know what should I do now, because I'mm really confused in this problem.

in Controller for CSV Import

```
function import()
    {

       $this->load->library('csvreader');
       $result =   $this->csvreader->parse_file('./application/upload/financialloss.csv');

        foreach($result as $value=>$key){
            $date_report = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            $handlingdate = $key['Handling Date'];
            $handlingdate2 = strtotime($handlingdate);
            $handlingdate3 = date('Y-m-d',$handlingdate2);

            $nominal_awal = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $key['Transactions Nominal'])));
            $nominal = str_replace(",","", $key['Transactions Nominal']);
            $nominal1 = str_replace(".","", $nominal);
            $nominal2 = str_replace("Rp","", $nominal1);


            $tblfinancialloss = array(
                'handlingdate'                  => $handlingdate3,
                'lossdate'                      => $key['Loss Date'],
                'ticketid'                      => $key['Ticket ID'],
                'reporteremail'                 => $key['Reporter Email'],
                'reporterusername'              => $key['Reporter Username'],
                'transactionsfraud'             => $key['Transactions Fraud'],
                'transactionsfinancialloss'     => $key['Transactions Financial Loss'],
                'transactionsnominal'           => $nominal2,
                'cityofuser'                    => $key['City of User'],
                'provinceofuser'                => $key['Province of User'],
                'transactionscategory'          => $key['Transactions Category'],
                'casecategory'                  => $key['Case Category'],
                'sourcedata'                    => $key['Source Data'],
                'linkphisingmedia'              => $key['Link Phising Media'],
                'notesloss'                     => $key['Notes'],
                'dateinput'                     => $date_report,
                'inputby'                       => "by ".$this->session->userdata('name')

            );
            if(empty($key['Loss Date'])){       
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','TES1');
            redirect(base_url()."index.php/DashboardFinancial/AddFinancialLoss");
            }
            else{           
            $this->Csv_Import_model->insert($tblfinancialloss);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msgs',' data, uploaded today !');
            }
        }
        //unlink('./assets/data.csv');
    }
```

And this is My Model for CSV Import

```
function insert($data)
    {
        $this->dbfinanciallossandsave= $this->load->database('financiallossandsave', TRUE);
        $insert_query1 = $this->dbfinanciallossandsave->insert_string('tblfinancialloss', $data);
        $insert_query = str_replace('INSERT INTO','INSERT IGNORE INTO',$insert_query1);
        $date = date("Y-m-d");  
        $this->dbfinanciallossandsave->where('handlingdate <=', $date);
        //$this->dbfinanciallossandsave->where('lossdate <=', $date);
        $this->dbfinanciallossandsave->query($insert_query); 
    }
```

And my model for where condition can't work. Can you help me?

Comment: what type of error do you get?

Comment: the result is no error, only data with predetermined conditions do not match.

Comment: $date = date("Y-m-d");  
        $this->dbfinanciallossandsave->where('handlingdate <=', $date);

Comment: I think you should try with an update query not insert.

Comment: But i need to insert with file upload

Comment: Ok then remove `where` because you can not use `where` in insert query instead of `where` you can use `if-else` condition for executing that.

Comment: Oh okaay... i use if else in my controller.

Comment: Yes definitely...